# Applescript to remove items from dock

Tags: automation, applescript, dock

I'm trying to remove (all) items from the dock. I can remove them by name like so:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell UI element "Launchpad" of list 1 of process "Dock"
        perform action "AXShowMenu"
        click menu item "Remove from Dock" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

But I'd like to pull the list of current items and iterate over them.
[This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245301/can-applescript-list-all-the-applications-placed-in-the-dock) seems to cover how to get the list. What I'd like to do is tweak the above code to operate inside of a loop. I would guess that referencing the current item of the list inside the loop would be done with "thisRecord". I think I'm misunderstanding how to convert "thisRecord" into something I can reference within system events.

```
set plistpath to (path to preferences folder as text) & "com.apple.dock.plist"

tell application "System Events"
    set plistContents to contents of property list file plistpath
    set pListItems to value of plistContents
end tell
set persistentAppsList to |persistent-apps| of pListItems

set dockAppsList to {}
repeat with thisRecord in persistentAppsList
    set end of dockAppsList to |file-label| of |tile-data| of thisRecord
    tell application "System Events"
        tell UI element application thisRecord
            perform action "AXShowMenu"
            click menu item "Remove from Dock" of menu 1
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As an alternative... Here is a much more straight forwards approach to removing the persistent apps on the **Dock** found in the `persistent-apps` *key* of the `com.apple.dock.plist` file:

In **Terminal**, do the following to first backup the target file:

1. `cd ~/Library/Preferences`
2. `cp -a com.apple.dock.plist com.apple.dock.plist.bak`

Now to remove the *persistent apps*, use the following *compound command*:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock persistent-apps; killall Dock
```

If later you want to restore the backup, use the following *compound command*:

```
 cd ~/Library/Preferences; rm com.apple.dock.plist; cp -a com.apple.dock.plist.bak com.apple.dock.plist; killall Dock
```

If for some reason you need to do this with **AppleScript**, you can use the `do shell script` *command* to run these *shell commands*.

---

Note: In your OP you stated "I'm trying to remove (all) items from the dock." and the *code* you've presented only focuses on the apps stored under the `persistent-apps` *key*. There are also additional *items* that can show on the **Dock**, the first being the default `persistent-others`, which has the **Downloads** *stack* and other items you've added to that section. Then with **macOS Mojave** there is `recent-apps` which shows between the two aforementioned sections (by *key* name) on the **Dock**. The same premise can be use on these *keys* as well, substituting `persistent-others` or `recent-apps` for `persistent-apps` in the `defaults delete ...` *compound command*.

Comment: I know I asked for applescript but I really like how clean and easy a 2 line answer is.

Comment: @jorgus, As I mentioned in the answer... “If for some reason you need to do this with **AppleScript**, you can use the `do shell script` _command_ to run these _shell commands_.”

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be wise to backup your "com.apple.dock.plist" file first.  These following two lines of AppleScript code will copy your current com.apple.dock.plist file to your Desktop.  This will come in handy if you want to revert your Dock icons back to the way they were before you ran the second script of this post.

```
set plistpath to (path to preferences folder as text) & "com.apple.dock.plist"
tell application "Finder" to duplicate alias plistpath to desktop
```

---

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
set plistpath to (path to preferences folder as text) & "com.apple.dock.plist"

tell application "System Events"
    set plistContents to contents of property list file plistpath
    set pListItems to value of plistContents
end tell
set persistentAppsList to |persistent-apps| of pListItems

set dockAppsList to {}
-- Gets app names and adds them to dockAppsList
repeat with i from 1 to count of persistentAppsList
    set thisItem to item i of persistentAppsList
    set appName to |file-label| of |tile-data| of thisItem
    set end of dockAppsList to appName
end repeat

-- Loops through each app in dockAppsList and removes each app from Dock
repeat with thisRecord in dockAppsList
    tell application "System Events"
        tell UI element thisRecord of list 1 of process "Dock"
            try
                perform action "AXShowMenu"
                click menu item "Options" of menu 1
                click menu item "Remove from Dock" of menu 1 of menu item "Options" of menu 1
            on error
                try
                    perform action "AXShowMenu"
                    click menu item "Remove from Dock" of menu 1
                end try
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

I realize I could have included everything in one large repeat loop. I thought it would be better ,for purposes of this script, to separate the two looping events in the event that somewhere else in your script you may want to refer back to items of `dockAppsList` so instead of "removing all from the dock" you may only want to remove items 1 through 5 of `dockAppsList` from the dock.

Comment: This code seems kind of destructive if you ask me.  It would probably be wise to backup your "com.apple.dock.plist" file first

Comment: ^ Thanks, could you provide a sample of syntax to do that?